# In Eclipse, when debugging, is there an easy way to see a variable's total memory size?

Tags: java, eclipse

From the Debug view, when looking at the Variables tab, is there a way to easily see how much of the heap a given variable is consuming?  (Something akin to Java's Heap Analysis Tool)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this will help:

[Memory Analyzer (MAT)](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)

> The Eclipse Memory Analyzer is a fast
>   and feature-rich Java heap analyzer
>   that helps you find memory leaks and
>   reduce memory consumption.
>
> Use the Memory Analyzer to analyze
>   productive heap dumps with hundreds of
>   millions of objects, quickly calculate
>   the retained sizes of objects, see who
>   is preventing the Garbage Collector
>   from collecting objects, run a report
>   to automatically extract leak
>   suspects.

Comment: i was seeking a tool that would let me see total memory usage per object during a live debugging session.

Comment: Exactly this is a poor answer. This tool requires a dump of the heap while the JVM is running and then analyzes the contents externally. An actual solution would add mouse-over memory sizes to variables from the variables page inside the live eclipse debugger.

Answer (score 1):

A half-measure would be to watch for changes in the total RunTime's used ram with something like:

`Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
long currInUse = rt.totalMemory() - rt.freeMemory();`

Comment: This does not answer the question.